# Group is not defined in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

Trying to create any paperjs objects, like Group and get error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Group is not defined"

But when I put it in `function onMouseUp(event){}` it creates without problems.

How can I create this object instantly after loading page?

This works good and I have new Group object

```
function onMouseUp(event) {
  objsGroup = new Group();
  objsGroup.addChild(path);}
```

This doesn't work (I have 'Group is not defined' error on first line) :

```
  objsGroup = new Group();

  function onMouseUp(event) {
    objsGroup.addChild(path);}
```

Comment: If you are working with paperscript, check if you are setting it up correctly. http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/

Comment: I read this article couple of times. I belive that I did everything right. The main question is why creation of different paperjs objects such as Group, Path, Layer are possible inside of onMouse actions and can't be done outside of them.

Comment: Post the code so we can see what's the situation.

Comment: Added code examples